# How to free a pSDL_Surface copied explicitly as a parameter with IMG_LOAD(path)?

Tags: memory-management, sdl, pascal

*(Note: I'm coding in Pascal)*

In the creator of a class `TQuest`, I initialize some objects with a pSDL_Surface given as a parameter as follows :

`quests.Add( CPopuQuest.create('Get money ! ','Get more than $10,000', IMG_LOAD(MONEY_ICON), 1000, 10) );`
(The interesting part is `IMG_LOAD(MONEY_ICON)` with MONEY_ICON the path to an image.

When I end my program, I get an error at the destructor of this CPopuQuest object in this line:

`if badge<>nil then SDL_FreeSurface(badge)`

(badge is the attribute where the pSDL_Surface instantiated by IMG_LOAD(MONEY_ICON) is copied)

It works most of the time, but from time a time I still get an error when closing the program ... If anyone can help :) (as you can see I'm quite confused with how IMG_LOAD works, what it returns, and how memory is allocated when its called).

Comment: Was it your intention that everyone should *guess* what error you get? Why are you confused about what `IMG_Load` returns? I didn't get that impression from anything you wrote above. It plainly returns a pointer to an `SDL_Surface`. Didn't you have to know that in order to declare `badge` and `CPopuQuest.Create`? What documentation are you using? The documentation at libsdl.org seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: I'm quite new to SDL (and Stackoverflow), even though I almsot finished developing a game with it :) ; So you may excuse this unclear question I asked.

The error I got is of type SIG..., don't remember exactly. And it doesn't always happen, and I don't know how to reproduce it, that's why I didn't give the exact error (but I'm sure that it's related to the memory management at the destructor).

Anyway, I'll try to look into the code and find where it comes from !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that `IMG_Load` returns will be safe to pass to `SDL_FreeSurface`, even if it returns a null pointer. (Thus, you don't need to check `badge <> nil` before calling `SDL_FreeSurface(badge)`.)

If your program crashes when you call `SDL_FreeSurface`, then it's due to other problems in your program. That function is the correct way to free anything that `IMG_Load` loads. Everything shown in this question is right.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have a memory leak. It may be not the surface but from another codes. Once a time, I make a mistake that accessing an array out of bound, it changes a surface and let the palette point not null(it should be null), when I call SDL_FreeSurface there is an error raised.